# Swift Mac OSX NSButton title color

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6, nsbutton

I would like to know how to change title color to a NSButton in swift, I've seen lots of examples in objective-c but I think in swift the implementation is different, can anyone provide me an example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this in `viewDidLoad` or somewhere.

In Swift 3:

```
    let pstyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    pstyle.alignment = .center

    button.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Title", attributes: [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.red, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : pstyle ])
```

Comment: In Swift 2 you need to change `.CenterTextAlignment` to `.Center`

Comment: Swift 3 version:  

    `let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()  
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center button.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Title", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.red, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle])`

Comment: What about vertical alignment?

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4**

I've added this as an additional answer since it changes only the requested attribute without overwriting or adding additional ones.

```
if let mutableAttributedTitle = button.attributedTitle.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableAttributedString {
    mutableAttributedTitle.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: NSColor.white, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: mutableAttributedTitle.length))
    button.attributedTitle = mutableAttributedTitle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift4

```
button.attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello World", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: style, NSAttributedStringKey.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)])
```

Comment: Xcode 9 with swift 4 isn't out yet and isn't GM either so although this might not change I think you are jumping the gun here

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
button.contentTintColor = NSColor.white
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var resendOTPButton: NSButton!

var buttonTextColorRef : NSColor = DisplayHexColorCode.whiteColor.asColor
self.resendOTPButton.setButtonTextColor(textColor: buttonTextColorRef)


func setButtonTextColor(textColor color: NSColor) {
    if #available(macOS 10.14, *) {
        self.contentTintColor = color
    } else {
        let newAttributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedTitle)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedTitle.length)
        newAttributedTitle.addAttributes([
            .foregroundColor: color,
        ], range: range)
        attributedTitle = newAttributedTitle
    }
}
```